# Pygame key pressed not working

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to follow this old youtube tutorial on how to create a game in Python using pygame. I've ran into a stump where I can't get the key pressed movements to work. Tutorial I've been following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4E9iq0BixA&t=228s

I press w, a, s, d... but nothing happens to the screen

```
import pygame
import sys
# import math


class Cam:
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0, 0), rot=(0, 0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.rot = list(rot)

    def update(self, dt, key):
        s = dt * 10

        if key[pygame.K_q]: self.pos[1] += s
        if key[pygame.K_e]: self.pos[1] -= s

        if key[pygame.K_w]: self.pos[2] += s
        if key[pygame.K_s]: self.pos[2] -= s
        if key[pygame.K_a]: self.pos[0] -= s
        if key[pygame.K_d]: self.pos[0] += s

pygame.init()
w, h = 400, 400; cx, cy = w//2, h//2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

verts = (-1, -1, -1), (1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1)
edges = (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 4), (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)

cam = Cam((0, 0, -5))

while True:
    dt = clock.tick()/1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for edge in edges:

        points = []
        for x, y, z in (verts[edge[0]], verts[edge[1]]):

            x -= cam.pos[0]
            y -= cam.pos[1]
            z -= cam.pos[2]

            f = 200/z
            x, y = x*f, y*f
            points += [(cx + int(x), cy + int(y))]
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0,), points[0], points[1], 1)

    pygame.display.flip()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    cam.update(dt, key)
```

Comment: That would be because their position definition is in the form of a `tuple`, a comma separated list of elements in parentheses, `(a,b,c)`, which can not be changed after creation, meaning that you will want to use a list, as a lists values can be changed.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill I will try your solution; thank you for answering..

Comment: I asked the original creator of this, and he/she says it's working perfectly from their end. Maybe i'm just not doing something right

Comment: It seems to work fine for me as well. I only dedented the `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))` line, so that the screen gets filled each frame. And the program crashes if I zoom in too far, but I can move the camera with the wasd keys correctly.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind I was mistaken, I didn't notice that inside the function the input was turned into a list. Look at the response given by @skrx, as it seems that that could be the issue.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill the overindented `screen.fill` is just one issue, but it can't explain why the keys are not working. I've got no idea what could cause this bug, especially since I can't reproduce it. @Brandon is that exactly the code that you're using or did you change anything?

Comment: This is really mind boggling to me. I've tried it on a couple of different computers and have been getting the same result. I even tried different operating systems, IDEs, and python versions. It's got to be something I am doing physically (installing pygame, pressing on the wrong window of focus, or something that I am incorrectly doing). Thank you for trying to help me though, @skrx

Comment: Maybe we can figure it out if you tell us step by step what you do.

Comment: idk why but it just started working for me when I came back to the project. I guess sometimes the best solution is giving yourself a break. thank you everyone for your time and help @skrx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**while True:**

```
dt = clock.tick()/1000
```

The problem might be here. If you debug the code and see the value of clock ticks that are stored in dt you will find that the value is 0. So when you press a key on the keyboard it doesn´t do anything because

s = dt*10 when dt:= 0 --> s= 0.

My solution was to define a static value simulating fps that are trying to get from the clock ticks. Define a value under.000 like:

**while True:**

```
**dt = .0009**
```

And that will work. (: